# Inequality . finding the maximum value.

Tags: inequality, optimization, radicals, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $k$ be a real number such that the inequality, 
$\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{4-x}>k$  has a solution. What is the maximum value of $k$.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: i do not know to approach this problem. some hints would be appreciated .

Comment: The first step would be to realize why there are any limits to anything here. What values of $x$ are possible?

Comment: Not considering complex field. 
i guess,  $x-1>0$ and $4-x>0$ ,right ?

Comment: @user1157 If we had been considering the complex field, $>$ would be meaningless, so we're not doing that. And you have almost the right inequalities (use $\geq$ instead). Next is to use those two inequalities to find what the actual bounds on $x$ are.

Comment: i actually  did that part by myself and lost my ways to solve it. you said the answer is $k=10$.  
Rozenberg used C-S to solve it. Did not understand his calculations.

Comment: $f(x)=\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{4-x}$, defined over $[1,4]$, is concave and symmetric with respect to $x=\frac{5}{2}$, hence the maximum is attained at such a point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{4-x}=\sqrt{3+2\sqrt{(x-1)(4-x)}}\geq\sqrt3.$$
The equality occurs for $x=1$.

Thus, $\sqrt3$ is a minimal value of $\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{4-x}.$

The maximal value we can get by C-S:
$$\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{4-x}\leq\sqrt{(1^2+1^2)(x-1+4-x)}=\sqrt{6}.$$
The equality occurs for $x=2.5.$

Thus, all $k<\sqrt{6}$ is valid and the maximal value of $k$ does not exist.

Comment: thanks. but did not actually understand.

Comment: What exactly you did not understand? About which line of my solution do you say?

Comment: cauchy-schwarz's inequality. i know it. but your that line seemed to be hard for me to understand. or i am missing something

Comment: C-S it's the following: $(a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2)(b_1^2+b_2^2+,,,+b_n)^2\geq(a_1b_a+a_2b_2+...+a_nb_n)^2.$ In our case $6=2\cdot3=(1^2+1^2)((\sqrt{x-1})^2+\sqrt{4-x})^2)\geq(\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{4-x})^2.$

Comment: got it man. it was dumb of me .Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The expression $\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{4-x}$ only makes sense when $x\in[1,4]$. What's the graph of the map$$\begin{array}{ccc}[1,4]&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\x&\mapsto&\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{4-x}?\end{array}$$